# How to force std::vector call a specific constructor depending on an instance of another class

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, allocator

Let's say I want to assign a unique id to every object of a certain class newly created, but not to those that are copied. I could to something like :

```cpp
int next_id = 0;    // ugly global variable

class Element {
    int id;
public:
    Element(){
        this->id = next_id++;
    }
    Element(const Element &other){
        this->id = other.id;
    }
};
```

and it would work with stl library, I can do

```cpp
vector<Element> list;
```

But instead of having a global variable, I need to have next_id inside another object :

```cpp
class Context {
    int next_id;
public:
    Element *createElement(){
        Element *element = new Element(this->next_id++);
        return element;
    }
};

class Element {
    int id;
public:
    Element(int id) : id(id) {
    }
    Element(const Element &other){
        this->id = other.id;
    }
};
```

So I can use it this way:

```
Element *element = context->createElement();
```

But I can't use it with vector.

I would like to make std::vector call the constructor of Element via a function like

```
context->createElement()
```

, ie something depending on a 'context' object, and call the regular copy constructor when resizing.

Is there any way to do this? For example by passing a functor instance to vector or something else?...

EDIT : To clarify a point. I mention the use of another `Context` class because I want the user be able to create a new series of id by creating a new `context` object and associating later `element`s to this new `context`. For example an equivalent problem would be to have an Element class that looks like this :

```cpp
class Element {
    Context *context;
public:
    Element(Context *context) : context(context){
    }
    Element(const Element &other){
        this->context = other.context;
    }
};
```

and searching for a way to specify a `context` object to `vector` when it calls the constructor.

Comment: Keep your first example and make `next_id` a `static`member of `Element`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see, why you want to have `next_id` in different class. The simpliest solution is to make `next_id` static member of `Element`.

```
class Element {
public:
    Element(){
        this->id = next_id++;
    }
    Element(const Element &other){
        this->id = other.id;
    }
private:
    int id;
    static int next_id;
};

int Element::next_id = 0;
```

This should do the trick. You don't need to have custom "alocator", which I think is nonsense.

If your goal with id is to have multiple classes, with unique id between them, use inheritance! Element would be father of all subclasses and it would take care of your completely unique IDs.

Comment: I think my example is misleading because my problem isn't actually to have unique ids. I want the user be able to begin a new series of ids by creating a new `Context` object. I will clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library effectively construct their element by calling `a.construct(p, args...)`. Correspondingly, you can use the `construct()` member of a custom allocator to customize how the ovjects are constructed. This approach does require that the custom allocator is used. This use can be enforced by making the constructors of the corresponding class `private` and providing anapproach to construction for the custom allocator.

Comment: but the allocator is a class, is it possible to pass an argument to the allocator in the declaration of the vector?

Comment: @OnurCelebi: the C++11 allocators are stateful, i.e., the necessary context can be referenced from there and the allocator is passed everywhere.

Comment: They are stateful during the lifetime of the vector, but is there a way to pass them an argument during the declaration of the vector?